# UITextView change dynamically font

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Hello i'm using the following code to detect new line on UITextView

```
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newLine:Bool = text == "\n"

    if newLine {
       println("new line")
    }
    return true
}
```

i want to change font when new line occurs first thing i try is to use

```
       if newLine {      
        textView.typingAttributes = highlightTypingAttributes
       } else {
          textView.typingAttributes = normalTypingAttributes
       }
```

the other thing is to set attributed string but it change the whole text i want only to append bold font after new line happens

any ideas?

Thanks